# Maximo - curl - use session id to access API

Tags: curl, cookies, maximo

I logged into Maximo via (Thanks @Dex)

```
curl --head --request POST 'https://domain/maximo/oslc/login' --header 'maxauth:bWF4YWRtaW46bWF4YWRtaW4='
```

I got this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 26 Aug 2020 10:20:27 GMT
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
Location: https://domain/maximo/webclient/login/login.jsp?appservauth=true
Content-Length: 0
Set-Cookie: WASPostParam=L21heGltby9vc2xjL2xvZ2lu.//////////8=.AAAAAA==.AA==; Path=/maximo/oslc/login; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: WASReqURL=https:///maximo/oslc/login; Path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2"
Content-Language: en-US
```

Now I am trying to reuse the above cookie to run a simple REST API to check my login

I am trying:

```
curl -v cookie "Token1=value1;Token2=value2" --request GET <domain>
```

Below is the request and response:

```
  $ curl -v --cookie "WASPostParam=L21heGltby9vc2xjL2xvZ2lu.//////////8=.AAAAAA==.AA==; Path=/maximo/oslc/login; HttpOnly;WASReqURL=https:///maximo/oslc/login; Path=/; HttpOnly" --request GET https://domain/maximo/oslc/whoami
    Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
      0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 

149.29.121.154...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to domain (149.29.121.154) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with domain port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: checking server certificate revocation
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 185 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 185 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with domain port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with domain port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 2732
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 2732 length 4096
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with domain port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 1364
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4096 length 4096
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with domain port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 2
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4098 length 5120
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with domain port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 328
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4426 length 5122
* schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 158 bytes...
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with domain port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 51
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 51 length 5122
* schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with domain port 443 (step 3/3)
* schannel: stored credential handle in session cache
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0> GET /maximo/oslc/whoami HTTP/1.1
> Host: domain
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: WASPostParam=L21heGltby9vc2xjL2xvZ2lu.//////////8=.AAAAAA==.AA==; Path=/maximo/oslc/login; HttpOnly;WASReqURL=https:///maximo/oslc/login; Path=/; HttpOnly
>
* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 103424
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: encrypted data got 409
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 409 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 380
* schannel: decrypted data added: 380
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 380 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 380 length 102400
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 380
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 102400
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Wed, 26 Aug 2020 10:44:21 GMT
< X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
< Location: https://domain/maximo/webclient/login/login.jsp?appservauth=true
< Content-Length: 0
< Set-Cookie: WASReqURL=https:///maximo/oslc/whoami; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2"
< Content-Language: en-US
<
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host domain left intact
```

Should the cookie be saved in a file and then reused?. If so,can I get the curl commands to save and re-use cookies. I tried a couple of different options, none which work.

Thank you
R

Comment: I don't think you are actually logged in. You are getting a 302 response, which is a redirect, instead of a 200 response with the body confirming you are logged in. And your redirect has the "appserverauth=true" appended to it. That usually means LDAP is being used for authentication instead of local Maximo. That in turn means you need to go back to use the "Authorization" header you were initially using.

Comment: When you do get a proper session cookie back though, you will need to save it and reuse it subsequent requests so you don't have send a username and password with each request. Whether you write it to file or not is sort of up to you, but usually your client would just store it in memory somewhere and send it along with any future requests.